# resque is not loading the rails environment properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I was converting a working application to process incoming requests via resque. The jobs get submitted to resque properly. The problem starts when the worker grabs a task and starts executing.

Inside my application I got an error with one of my models when i tried to refer to one of the fields.  class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
The call was 'Keyword.first.rule' This would return "Attempt to call private method".

The problem went away when i added the following snippet in the worker before it called my application

```
def self.perform(phone_number,message,short_code)
  k = Keyword.first
  k.rule
  Parser.new.parse_request(phone_number,message,short_code)
end
```

After I got passed this problem other random errors started cropping up on the code that used to work properly before. ex casecmp is not valid method.
I am convinced this is not an issue with my code because when i call the same methods from the rails console it works perfectly fine.

This is my setup
- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
- gem 1.3.5
- rails 2.3.8
- resque 1.17.1
- Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Worker

```
class ProcessMo
  @queue = :incoming_messages_queue

  def self.perform(phone_number,message,short_code)
    Parser.new.parse_request(phone_number,message,short_code)
  end

end
```

resque.rake

```
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it sounds like the following is before that section of code:

```
private
```